# onCreate getting called after returning from Email client sharing big pdf file with FileProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, oncreate, android-fileprovider

I am calling email client with intent chooser.

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//          emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Receipt Voucher from Vawsum");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please find the receipt voucher attached along with this mail.");
            Uri outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", new File(String.valueOf(new File(String.valueOf(pdfDir),  "VawsumVoucher.pdf"))));// - akash - to send third party apps big size files
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, outputFileUri);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
```

Here is the provider code in maifest file:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.trakkerz.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>
```

need help.

Comment: what problem you  faced?

Comment: when returning to activity after sending email onCreate() method getting called.I don't want to call onCreate(). new Instance of that activity getting created maybe.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to get the most our of Stack Overflow. Please _edit_ your question to explain exactly what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of vague formulated questions, but if you wait for the intent you should use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`

Use `onActivityResult()` to do the work you want done after

Comment: I tried with startActivityForResult(), but onCreate() and onActivityResult() both gets called.

Answer (score 0):

> onCreate getting called after returning from Email client sharing big pdf file with FileProvider

My guess is that your process was terminated while your app was not in the foreground. This is [perfectly normal](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle).

Comment: I think onResume() should be called when app is coming in foreground from background. @CommonsWave

Comment: @AkashMaity: If your process is terminated, when the user returns to your app, a new process is forked. Since your old activity was destroyed, a new activity instance will be created, and `onCreate()` will be called, in addition to having `onResume()` called (after `onCreate()`). Again, this is perfectly normal.